# linux + find word in file under directory but quickly

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following command

```
find /var  -type f -exec grep "param1" {} \; -print
```

With this command I can find the param1 string in any file under /var

but the time that it take for this is very long.

I need other possibility to find string in file but much more faster then my example

THX

yael

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
grep -r "string"
```

The find is not neccesary.

This is a good link, though outdated.

[link text](http://www.linfo.org/grep.html)

Also i think this belongs in superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the -l option to the grep command for a speed boost. To speed up the find command use:

```
find ... -exec sh -c '...' arg0 '{}' +


# grep ... -l: print files with matches, but stop scanning the file on the first match
grep -lsr "param1" /var

find /var -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -ls "param1" "$@"' arg0 '{}' +
find /var -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -ls "$0" "$@"' "param1" '{}' +
```

Comment: sorry but its not work 

 find /var -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -ls "$0" "$@"' "param1" '{}' + find: missing argument to `-exec'

Answer (score 1):

```
find /var -type f  | xargs grep "param1"
```

would be slightly faster (no process spawning for each file)

```
grep -r "param1" /var
```

would be slightly more so I think.

Comment: but if the files are "too much", this could cause problems. Moreover, better to use `-print0` and `-0` accordingly, and add the `-n` too to prevent preview possible problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try also using ack, which is "[better than grep](http://betterthangrep.com/)" in most cases. Among its features the ability to ignore typical garbage files by default (such as .svn or .git directories, core dumps, backup files), the ability to use a large set of predefined file classes, nice output formatting.

Comment: where I can download the ack?

Comment: @yael: Install it using your package manager (preferred) or download it at the link that **UncleZeiv** conveniently provided.

Comment: Just be careful when installing it from your distribution as there is often another package named "ack" around, which has nothing to do with this. In Ubuntu you want to `apt-get install ack-grep`. Happy acking :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use locate's index (if you don't depend on files that are added/removed)

```
grep "param1" $(locate -r '^/var')
```

Answer (score -1):

some of these command optimizations are helpful, but the biggest jump in speed I got from grepping 2 million files was to use a SSD Hard drive. Same queries took 1/5 of the time.