# Linux : Search for a Particular word in a List of files under a directory

Tags: linux

I have a big list of log files in a particular directory  , related to my java  Application  under my Linux  Remote Servers .

**When i do ls on that particular directory it shows a list of files (nearly 100 files )**

Now in that List of files , i need to find out a particular word , please tell me , how can i do this ??

The problem is that I cannot open each and every file and search for that word using  /

Please tell me how can i search for a word in the list of files provided .

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux + find word in file under directory but quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965050/linux-find-word-in-file-under-directory-but-quickly)

Comment: I mean, not exactly duplicate, but the answer is also there, which could easily be found in the related questions.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`grep` is made for this.

Use:

- `grep myword *` for a simple word
- `grep 'my sentence' *` for a literal string
- `grep "I am ${USER}" *` when you need variable replacement

You can also use regular expressions.

Add `-r` for recursive and `-n` to show the line number of matching lines.

And check `man grep`.

Comment: @cgnorthcutt not really. For subdirectories you need to use the recursive flag. For 'a directory' where you already are, like in the OP case, you don't. Also, the `-n` flag is completely optional, nothing to be associated with "you need to".

Comment: To include subdirectories, you need to use the recursive flag "-r", like `grep -r "string" *` See Ashkan's answer. and cornuz's comment.

Answer (score 65):

You can use this command:

```
grep -rn "string" *
```

n for showing line number with the filename
r for recursive

Answer (score 13):

This is a very frequent task in linux. I use grep -rn '' . all the time to do this. -r for recursive (folder and subfolders) -n so it gives the line numbers, the dot stands for the current directory.

```
grep -rn '<word or regex>' <location>
```

do a

```
man grep
```

for more options

Answer (score 6):

also you can try the following.

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec grep "<yourword" /dev/null {} \;
```

It gets all the files with .java extension and searches  'yourword' in each file, if it presents, it lists the file.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

You could club find with exec as follows to get the list of the files as well as the occurrence of the word/string that you are looking for

```
find . -exec grep "my word" '{}' \; -print
```

Answer (score 2):

use this command
`grep "your word" searchDirectory/*.log`

Get more on this link

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-recursively-search-all-files-for-words/

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) command.

You can read [15 Practical Grep Command Examples In Linux / UNIX](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/) for some samples.